# Codeigniter query for table truncate

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

> Codeigniter query for table truncate.

**Like mysqul query**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$this->db->truncate('table_name');
```

View more [a database table truncate](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)